# Change the first 0s group into 3s

Tags: matlab, replace

I have this matrix in matlab.

[image]

It has 31 rows and 546 columns.

I need to change the first group of zeros (until before the 2s) in each column into 3s, but the second group of 0s (after the 1s) should stay as 0s. SO at the end I should a matrix like this

[image]

Comment: Please at least follow the prompt from the markdown hyperlink to external contents and provide a description of what is waiting at the other end. Note that you can format tables using markdown, see post edit help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = 1;
while ~ismember(1,yourmatrix(a,:))
    line = yourmatrix(a,:);
    line(line==0)=3;
    yourmatrix(a,:) = line;
    a=a+1;
end
```

The *ismember* function checks if elements are members of an array. Until a line contains the number 1, it replaces every 0 with a 3 per line.

You can read more about the *ismember* function [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html) and about matrix indexing [here](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Also, don't use `i` as a variable because the complex unit is defined as that in matlab `i := sqrt(-1)`

Comment: I didn't try your code, but wouldn't this solution throw an error when trying to check the `while` condition for `a = size(yourmatrix, 1) + 1`? Then using an outer `for` loop might be better.